# Do you need to save ParseUser before Cloud Function Calls?

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I have an app on unity that uses ParseUser to store the user Level and Experience. When the user reaches a new Level a ParseCloud function call is made. However whenever user is retrieved via:

`Parse.Cloud.define("LevelUp", function (request, response){
    var user = request.user;
});`

All the attributes in user have the values that are currently saved on the database, but not the ones that the ParseUser that made the request have in the Parse client.

Do I need to call `ParseUser.CurrentUser.SaveAsync();` before every call to the server to get current user values or is there a way to send the dirty ParseUser values to the ParseCloud function and update them from that function.

Thanks!

Comment: You can send params on `Parse.Cloud.run("functionName", params)` and access them with `request.params`.  If you decide to save the user, maybe change the name so it's apparent to the caller, like "LevelUpAndSaveUser".

Comment: If I try to send a ParseObject in params I get the `ArgumentException: ParseObjects not allowed here.`. 

Maybe an answer would be to send the new level in the params , do the required modifications and then fetch the modifications after the function returns?. I was hoping to to the modification, save and fetch in one call to the server.

Comment: Right, you'll want to send regular objects, not parse objects.  I think in Unity (but as a caveat, I learned what Unity is about 12 seconds ago), you can pass objects that implement "IDictionary<string, T>". So you'd need to pluck the changes out of the user and build one of those.

Comment: Ah ok, make sense, I made some changes to my approach, based on what you mentioned, I now instead make a query for the new level information, and apply it on the client side and save the Parse user in my normal app flow.  Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer yes.

Long answer: Not necessarily, but you need to wrap the unsaved (or dirty) attributes in an object and send it to ParseCloud, due the fact that you can't send ParseObject in a ParseCloud call.

In my case, I ended up changing the approach: retrieve the necessary
information about the level, and do the modifications on the ParseUser on the client.